# Custom validation for hidden/non-bound field in Blazor

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, mudblazor

I'm working with Blazor for the first time (also the first time I've worked with .NET in a few years so I'm rusty), and an additional component library that my team and I have decided to use with Blazor is [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/). Right now I'm working on a page that has an [Autocomplete](https://mudblazor.com/components/autocomplete#api) component.

What I'm trying to do is to use an Autocomplete feature to pull up a list of Books that a user can add to a list. At least one Book must be in the list. My problem is that because of how MudAutocomplete works, I'm unable to bind it to a list, so I have the Book appended to a list on a click event. However, hitting the submit button isn't hitting either of the validations I've implemented and I can't seem to figure out why.

I've got the following code:

```
<MudForm @ref="form" @bind-isValid="@success" bind-errors="@errors">
    <MudAutocomplete T="Book" Label="Select Book(s)" ValueChanged="@(b => AppendBookToList(b))" SearchFunc="@SearchBooks" MinCharacters="4" ToStringFunc="@(b => b == null ? null : $"{b.Name + " by " + b.Author}")" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ValidateRequiredBooks)">
    </MudAutocomplete>
    
    <!-- List books that were selected from the autocomplete -->
    @foreach (var b in Books)
    {
        <MudChip Color="Color.Primary" OnClose="RemoveRequester" Text="b.Id">@b.Name by @b.Author</MudChip>
    }
    <!-- I guess use this area below to secretly bind the Books field? Not sure how to display the validation error otherwise -->
    <MudField @bind-Value="@Books"></MudField>
    
    ...
    
    <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="ml-auto" OnClick="@(() => form.Validate())">Submit</MudButton>
</MudForm>

...

@code {
    ...
    
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
    
    [BooksValidation(ErrorMessage = "At least one Book required.")]
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    
    ...
    
    // This is not firing
    private IEnumerable<string> ValidateRequiredBooks(string value)
    {
        if (Books.Count == 0)
        {
            yield return "At least one Book must be selected.";
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also created the following custom validation attribute for my `Books` variable:

```
public class BooksValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Breakpoint here isn't getting hit
        var listValue = value as List<Book>;
        if (listValue != null && listValue.Count != 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why these aren't working at all? It's driving me up a wall

Answer (score 0):

I use Validation attribute like:

```
Validation="@(new BooksValidationAttribute())"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).